# Query to interpret data in two tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am doing a research project for a lending company. They want to create a table in a report that shows if a borrower is a female head of the household or not. The criteria is the primary borrower must be female and there must not be a co-borrower.

The data is contained in two tables. The loan table has the loan_number (pk), amount, and other non-relevant columns. A sample table would look like the following:

[image]

The borrower table has loan_number, borrower_position, gender, and other non-relevant columns. the gender column contains either 'Female' or 'Male'. The borrower_position column contains either the integer 1 or 2, 1 being a Primary borrower and 2 being a co-borrower. A sample of the borrower table is as follows:

[image]

When I run the query, I am expected to get back a resulting table that looks like the follow:

[image]

The problem is, I am not exactly sure how to run this sort of a query in SQL Server. Can someone assist me?

Comment: What was the query you ran? Please do include it. It's difficult to see where you went wrong, if we don't have the code you wrote.

Comment: There is no code. As I mentioned, I have no clue how to write this query. I just know what the results are suppose to be. I just cannot wrap my head around this one.

Comment: I suggest looking up [Aggregate Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`GROUP BY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) first then. have a go, and add your attempt to your question if you don't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't write your query for you, but I'll help you "wrap your head around it".  Just break it down into simple steps:

Your desired result consists of a unique Row Header (Yes or No) and two aggregations, a COUNT and a SUM.

So you're going to do a simple GROUPING by the `Female Head` column, and then use simple aggregate functions to get the other two columns.

The tricky part, I assume, is how to get the `Female Head` column.   You can use a CASE expression to check:   If {some conditions} are true, then this column is a "Yes", else "No".

For {Some Conditions} obviously one of them is that `Gender` = 'Female'.   The other is trickier, you need to check to see if there is another row with the same `Loan Number` where the `Gender` = 'Male'.   If either of the borrowers is 'Male' then it really doesn't matter which is primary or secondary, because your requirement are that there must be no Male borrower on the loan.   You will need to check this with a subquery, and I would suggest looking into the EXISTS() function for this.

Then just put it all together:   The `Female Head` column is the CASE expression that returns "Yes" or "No".  The other two columns are COUNT and SUM functions, and you need to GROUP BY the CASE expression.

Comment: Exists is the part I needed to figure out the riddle. Thanks!